# ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'pkg' ( see: 'rvm usage' )

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to run

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

and I get the following message

```
ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'pkg' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

I installed rvm by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

I have searched online but I have only found a similar error stating that **package**

has changed to **pkg**, but in this case I am using **pkg**. Any ideas? 
I am using Ubuntu 11.10 x64

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I didn't install rvm as I should.

First uninstall ruby-rvm by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-rvm
```

Then install rvm by running:

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

like the [instructions here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

Comment: I removed my rvm as mentioned, then this other command did nothing and link does not work.

Comment: The link is over two years old, it doesn't seem to be active anymore, sorry